# How do you pass a predicate through a relationship in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to get players that have `timeOnIce`and has set up my predicate as such.  I was hoping it would only return the players that a value in `timeOnIce`

```
lazy var fetchedResultsControllerAllPlayersWithShifts: NSFetchedResultsController<Players> = {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Players> = Players.fetchRequest()
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Players.lastName), ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    let predicate               = NSPredicate(format: "%K > 0", #keyPath(Players.playersShiftRelationship.timeOnIce))
    fetchRequest.predicate      = predicate

    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [#keyPath(Shifts.playersRelationship)]

    let fetchedResultsControllerAllPlayersWithShifts = NSFetchedResultsController( fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    fetchedResultsControllerAllPlayersWithShifts.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsControllerAllPlayersWithShifts
}()
```

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath playersRelationship passed to setPropertiesToFetch:'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching **Players**, but setting up properties to fetch from **Shifts**

**Edit:**

**fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch**  just setting up list of fields to preload. If it is not specified, fetchRequest will return you array of referenced to database, but due to optimisation all fields would be left to be loaded on demand (CoreData assume that you will not use all data at once). But if you sure that you need some specific fields (want to save SQL from running another request and win several ms) you can specify what properties you want to preload by this property.

Definitely it can't preload fields that belong to another table.

Comment: If I do the inverse and search for `Player` I get all the records that match the predicate.  If the case of 'Player' I use `NSPredicate(format: "ANY %K > 0", #keyPath(Players.playersShiftRelationship.timeOnIce))' and it returns 11 rows, which is great, but I really only need the 'Player' and not every records for `timeOnIce`

Comment: You asking to pre-load value for **Shifts.playersRelationship** from table **Players**.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I guess I have to approach this a little different.  Possible two queries (sub-query) to get what I'm after.